# finding the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}[ \lim_{ y \to 0}x\sin\frac{1}{y}]$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

limit  $$\lim_{x \to 0}[ \lim_{ y \to 0}f(x,y)]$$

Given :
$$f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x\sin\frac{1}{y}  & \mbox{if } y \ne 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } y = 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
this would mean since: $y\neq0$

we need to find :

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}[\lim_{y\to0}x\sin\frac{1}{y}]$$

My approach was let the limit be L then it's clear that :
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} -x \geq L \geq \lim_{x\to 0} x$$

So the limit must be 0.

But it's given to be not defined.

Comment: Look at the graph of $\sin(\frac{1}{y})$ near $0$ to see why it is not defined. More formally you could consider the sequences $y_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n},y'_n=\frac{1}{\pi/2+2\pi n}$ and see what you get for $f(x,y_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the approach you took, is that you suppose that the limit exists by using the letter $L$ to designate it. But for $x \ne 0$ given,

$$\lim_{y\to 0}x\sin\frac{1}{y}$$ doesn't exist as in any neighborhood of $0$ the map $y \mapsto x\sin\frac{1}{y}$ takes both values $x, -x$. Therefore $\lim_{y\to 0}x\sin\frac{1}{y}$ is not defined and consequently $ \lim_{x\to 0}[\lim_{y\to 0}x\sin\frac{1}{y}]$ isn't either.

However:

- the map $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ as $\vert f(x,y) \vert \le
     \vert x \vert$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.
- and is not continuous at any $(x,0)$ when $x \neq 0$.

Comment: That's what I thought but it just seems super weird, like when we consider the outer limit too it shouldn't really matter? Also both the logic kinda seem circular one is limit exists so the limit exist and one is limit doesn't exist so it doesn't? I am super confused Why would we choose one over the other

Comment: What you discovered is that indeed the limit for multivariate maps **depends** on the order you consider the variables!

Comment: I guess, but it seems super weird that the lim (x,y) -> (0,0) exists( according to delta epsilon) but this doesn't? like what does that even mean?

Comment: Wikipedia article [iterated limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit) provides conditions for the equality of the limits.